# How to cross-compile LuaJIT for Windows from Linux using CMAKE?

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, luajit

I am having a weird problem. I am attempting to automatically pull in, compile, and statically link LuaJIT 2.1-beta3 via CMAKE. The process works on linux, but if I attempt to cross compile for Windows via mingw, it errors:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/luajit.dir/build.make:74: luajit/src/luajit-stamp/luajit-install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:136: CMakeFiles/luajit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

The CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(lunar-dreamland VERSION 0.1.0)

include(ExternalProject)

set(luajit_CC "gcc -m32")
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    ExternalProject_Add(luajit
        URL http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-2.1.0-beta3.tar.gz
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/luajit
        SOURCE_SUBDIR src
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND make HOST_CC=${luajit_CC} CROSS=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}- TARGET_SYS=Windows BUILDMODE=static
        INSTALL_COMMAND make -I ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/luajit install PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/luajit-2.1.0-beta3
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    )
else()
    ExternalProject_Add(luajit
        URL http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-2.1.0-beta3.tar.gz
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/luajit
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND make CC=${luajit_CC} BUILDMODE=static
        INSTALL_COMMAND make install PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/luajit-2.1.0-beta3
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    )
endif()
ExternalProject_Get_Property(luajit install_dir)


add_library(hookerino SHARED hookerino/main.cpp hookerino/sigscan.cpp)
set_target_properties(hookerino PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
add_dependencies(hookerino luajit)
target_include_directories(hookerino PUBLIC ${install_dir}/include/luajit-2.1)
target_link_directories(hookerino PUBLIC ${install_dir}/lib)
target_link_libraries(hookerino luajit-5.1)

add_library(byondffi SHARED byondffi/dllmain.cpp byondffi/sigscan.cpp)
set_target_properties(byondffi PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")

add_library(maptick SHARED maptick/dllmain.cpp maptick/sigscan.cpp)
set_target_properties(maptick PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
```

the toolchain file i'm using:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX i686-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

If I remove the PREFIX from LuaJIT's ExternalProject_Add, it will error while compiling, on `DYNLINK libluajit.so`, but LuaJIT's `make install` will fail, even if I specify the directory.

Comment: Tsyvarev - the LuaJIT `make install` target only exists in the LuaJIT root directory Makefile.

Comment: Oh, that is the output from the *subproject*, not from the main project, sorry for noise. Windows version of your `ExternalProject_Add` call has `SOURCE_SUBDIR src` parameter, which is absent in Linux version. Is it intentional difference?

Comment: Tsyvarev -- Yes, when it tries to DYNLINK on the Windows version, it can't find all the object files, which are in `src`.

Comment: When build your main project, you may add `VERBOSE=1` parameter to `make` to see exact command lines which are executed. Have you tried to execute commands for build and install luajit **without CMake**, directly in mingw terminal?